# How migration multi-dbs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, multi-database

How do I build multi databases environments in Rails?

of course, I know, using "establish_connection" allow to connect specified database, but no longer good to migration.

In the best condition, when "rake db:migrate", each tables are created in pertinent databases.

My environment is below:

> Ruby 2.1.1
>   Rails 4.1
>   MySQL 5.6.13

Comment: Have you tried looking at gems like [connection_ninja](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja) or [multidb](https://github.com/atombender/multidb)?

Comment: Thanks! not tried yet, I'll try that.